# Add padding to HTML text input field

Tags: html, css, text, input, textbox

I want to add some space to the right of an `<input type="text" />` so that there's some empty space on the right of the field.

So, instead of [image], I'd get [image].

So, same behavior just some empty space to the right.

I've tried using `padding-right`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there a way to do this (or fake it)?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

padding-right works for me in Firefox/Chrome on Windows but not in IE.  Welcome to the wonderful world of IE standards non-compliance.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/SfPju/466/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="foo" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo
{
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 119):

You can provide padding to an input like this:

HTML:

```
<input type=text id=firstname />
```

CSS:

```
input {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

however I would also add:

```
input {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Box sizing makes the input width stay at 250px rather than increase to 260px due to the padding.

[For reference](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Answer (score 7):

padding-right should work.  Example linked.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ged8/

Answer (score 3):

### HTML

```
<div class="FieldElement"><input /></div>
<div class="searchIcon"><input type="submit" /></div>
```

### For Other Browsers:

```
.FieldElement input {
width: 413px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding: 0 2.5em 0 0.5em;
}

.searchIcon
{
 background: url(searchicon-image-path) no-repeat;
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
 text-indent: -999em;
 display: inline-block;
 left: 432px;
 top: 9px;
}
```

### For IE:

```
.FieldElement input {
width: 380px;
border:0;
}

.FieldElement {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 width: 455px;     
 }

.searchIcon
{
 background: url(searchicon-image-path) no-repeat;
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
 text-indent: -999em;
 display: inline-block;
 left: 432px;
 top: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can solve this, taking the `input` tag inside a `div`,
then put the padding property on `div` tag. This work's for me...

Like this:

```
<div class="paded">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

and css:

```
.paded{
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input class="form-control search-query input_style" placeholder="Search…"  name="" title="Search for:" type="text">


.input_style
{
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: add input_style class in your input tag & add this code in your css file

Comment: Add more info about your solution

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, fixing the width of the parent container with padding right fixed it for me (to prevent changing the size of the input when padding ) .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).