# is there a way to give left padding inside the input element so to separate user typed text and border of input element

Tags: html, css

I want to give left padding inside the input element so to separate user typed text and border of input element.
[image]

Comment: What is your current CSS? Please provide your code so we can see what you have already tried. FWIW it should be as simple as:  `input { padding-left: 10px; }` ;)

Comment: Yes, you can do `input {padding-left: 9001px;}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add padding to HTML text input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586302/add-padding-to-html-text-input-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide left padding to an input like this:

```
input[type=text] {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```